# Searching for element in a list

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list as such:

```
$DistrictCodes = "EA,BC,OC,NC,ME,RA,CM,NE";
```

I am trying find nth value in the list whose value equals "ME".
So here is what I do:

```
$Mydistrict = "ME";
$DistrictCodes = "EA,BC,OC,NC,ME,RA,CM,NE";
$MyDistrictArray = array($DistrictCodes);
$MyDisPos = array_search($Mydistrict, $MyDistrictArray);
echo "MyDisPos = $MyDisPos <br>";
```

However, it is not working? Why?
What I need is to figure out which element of the list has a value of ME and come up with 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7.

Comment: What is $OutageDistrictCodes ?

Comment: yeah, looks like that should just be `array($DistrictCodes);`

Comment: $MyDistrictArray = explode(',', $OutageDistrictCodes);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, to convert `$DistrictCodes` to an array you can use [explode](http://php.net/explode).

```
<?php

$Mydistrict = "ME";
$DistrictCodes = "EA,BC,OC,NC,ME,RA,CM,NE";
$MyDistrictArray = explode(',', $DistrictCodes);
$MyDisPos = array_search($Mydistrict, $MyDistrictArray);
echo "MyDisPos = $MyDisPos <br>";

// MyDisPos = 4 <br>
```

http://3v4l.org/DYV0K

Comment: I actually wrote the answer a few minutes before that but was away from my desk so just [jammed it in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030961/searching-for-element-in-a-list/31031183?noredirect=1#comment-50086662). ;p

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to convert this into array, in PHP we have this awesome function that represents search from a string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php

```
<?php

$Mydistrict = "ME";
$DistrictCodes = "EA,BC,OC,NC,ME,RA,CM,NE";
$output = strpbrk($Mydistrict, $DistrictCodes);

echo $output;
//output-> ME
```

http://3v4l.org/ah1h8

Comment: Interesting function. I'll make a note of that.

Comment: I think the answer he wanted was the position in the array, but that's a cool function anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My 5 pences :)

```
$Mydistrict = "ME";
$DistrictCodes = "EA,BC,OC,NC,ME,RA,CM,NE";

$MyDisPos = strpos($DistrictCodes,$Mydistrict) / 3;
echo "MyDisPos = $MyDisPos <br>";
```

Comment: *"My 5 pences"* - haha! Around here we say *"My 2 cents"*. So I take it that 5 pence equals 2 cents? ;-) I'd have to look up the exchange rates.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  have to look the other proposals :)